# How to merge 10 array keys and values , and update the particular array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

We are looking a function that can merge the array keys and values and update it particularly.

```
$array = array('testing1','testing2','testing3','testing4','testing5','testing6','testing7','testing8','testing9','testing10','testing11','testing12','testing13','testing14');
```

we just want to merge 10 values with 'space' like this.

```
$finalarray = array('testing1 testing2 testing3 testing4 testing5 testing6 testing7 testing8 testing9 testing10', 'testing11 testing12 testing13 testing14');
```

Is there any function that do same thing in PHP ?

Comment: And what would `$finalarray` look like if there were, say 24 strings in the original one isntead of 14? Would it have two strings containing 10 elements of the original each and a third one containing the remaining 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
    $array = array('testing1','testing2','testing3','testing4','testing5','testing6','testing7','testing8','testing9','testing10','testing11','testing12','testing13','testing14');
    $final = array_chunk($array,10);    
    $final = array_map(function ($n){return implode(" ", $n);}, $final);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'testing1 testing2 testing3 testing4 testing5 testing6 testing7 testing8 testing9 testing10' (length=90)
  1 => string 'testing11 testing12 testing13 testing14' (length=39)
```

Comment: hm, I think the OP wanted the first ten in one string and the rest in another ;)

Comment: Oh .. i Would update the code , added `array_slice` to the answer

Comment: It merge the whole values in single element, i require the first 10 values in first key, the another 10 on second key, and the remaining balance(which is less than 10 or 10) is on another key.

Comment: when we print_r($final), then it prints values like this `Array ( [0] => testing1 testing2 testing3 testing4 testing5 testing6 testing7 testing8 testing9 testing10 ) ` , but we require values in this type `Array ( [0] => testing1 testing2 testing3 testing4 testing5 testing6 testing7 testing8 testing9 testing10 [1] => testing11 testing12 testing13 testing14 ) `

Comment: Thanks for all, for making this script :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any direct php function in my mind, but you can try something like this:

```
$newArray = count($array) > 0 ? array ($array[0]) : array();
for ($i=1;$i<count($array);$i++) {
    if ($i % 10 == 0) {
       $finalarray[] = $newArray;
       $newArray = array ($array[$i]);
    } else {
       $newArray[] = $array[$i];
    }
}
if ( count($newArray) > 0 ) {
    $finalarray[] = $newArray;
}
```

Comment: when we print_r($finalarray); , then it prints these values `Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( [0] => testing2 [1] => testing3 [2] => testing4 [3] => testing5 [4] => testing6 [5] => testing7 [6] => testing8 [7] => testing9 [8] => testing10 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => testing12 [1] => testing13 [2] => testing14 ) )`